# eBay Trading API ReviseItemRequest add ShipToLocations

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm testing a PHP library that uses the eBay Trading XML API to revise an item and add international locations at the item level, the seller is setup as a US seller, this is the type of XML file that my application is sending, this item is under the business industrial category and it's a fixed price item with best offer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ReviseItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Item>
    <Site>US</Site>
    <ItemID>110120361608</ItemID>
    <ShipToLocations>Americas</ShipToLocations>
    <ShipToLocations>Europe</ShipToLocations>
    <ShipToLocations>Asia</ShipToLocations>
    <ShipToLocations>AU</ShipToLocations>
  </Item>
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <EBayAuthToken>Token_Auth</EBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</ReviseItemRequest>
```

However, the listing doesn't get updated, eBay returns a `success` response, but it looks like it ignores the `shipToLocations`. However, if I use the web interface, I can setup the `ShipToLocations` without problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviseItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2013-09-10T04:02:02.634Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>837</Version>
  <Build>E837_UNI_API5_16341562_R1</Build>
  <ItemID>110122614402</ItemID> .....
```

I've read the documentation on eBay in depth and I can't find a restriction or constraint that says that will ignore this revision.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually this was a bug on eBay

You can find more information on eBay developers forum,
questions/3635/bug-trading-api-when-shippingttypefreightflat-inte.html#answer-5652

And after following up for several months with eBay support, just two months ago, the bug was fixed, and I was able to programatically push all listings to support international shipping with the Trading API.

Hope this helps to someone having the same problem.